# PyTorch - Custom ReLU squared Implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I work on a project and I want to implement the ReLU squared activation function (max{0,x^2}). Is it ok to call it like:

```
# example code
    def forward(self, x):
        s = torch.relu(x**2)
        return s
```

Or should I implement the activation function on my own? In the second case could you please provide me an example on how to do so?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should be fine, but you shouldn't get negative numbers out of `**2` (assuming you're not dealing with complex numbers)... so why ReLU?

Comment: @Berriel I want to approximate square functions using a deep net architecture

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make much sense to compute `max(0, x**2)` because `x**2 >= 0` no matter what.

You probably want to compute `max(0, x) ** 2` instead:

```
s = torch.pow(torch.relu(x), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
s = torch.relu(torch.pow(x, 2))
```

instead. But otherwise, this is fine.